# nginx allow sending redirect from app to client

Tags: nginx, redirect, http

I am trying to redirect a user back to my mobile-app after successful login. (linking back to the app)

For this, I send a `307` response with this link: `exp://192.168.178.33:19000?steamId=76561198154889373`

My server code written in go looks like this:

```go
http.Redirect(w, r, redirectUrl+"?steamId="+steamId, 307)
```

The `nginx` works as a reverse proxy loadbalancing to 2 Servers running the rest-API.

here is the config:

```
upstream rest_api {
        server 123.456.789.123:8081 fail_timeout=10s;
        server 111.222.333.444:8081 fail_timeout=10s weight=5;
    }


        server {
             listen          443 ssl ipv6only=on;
             ssl_protocols SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

             server_name     example.com www.example.com;

             ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/chain.crt;
         ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.key;

         root /usr/share/nginx/html;

         location / {
                 index index.html index.htm;
         include /etc/nginx/headers/security_headers.conf;
         include /etc/nginx/headers/default_headers.conf;
             }

             location /hi {
                  index hi.html;
             }

         location ~* /notfound {
                 index not_found.html;
             }
        }

        server {
             listen          443 ssl;
             ssl_protocols SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

             server_name     api.example.com;

             ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/chain.crt;
         ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.key;

         location / {
                 proxy_pass https://rest_api;
         include /etc/nginx/headers/security_headers.conf;
         include /etc/nginx/headers/default_headers.conf;
             }

        }

      
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
            server_name example.com;
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    }

    server {

             listen          443 ssl;
             ssl_protocols SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
             server_name     example.com;
             ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/chain.crt;
             ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.key;
             location ~* /notfound {
             root /usr/share/nginx/html/notfound;
                 index not_found.html;
             }

        }
```

When running the api without the `nginx` and accessing the `/login` route via `111.222.333.444:8081/login`, it works fine, and I get redirected. But when using the `nginx` as reverse proxy, I get this (note the title of the browser-window is `rest_api` just like the `upstream` in `nginx.conf`:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tlk3.png

link here because I dont have 10 reps yet.

How would I have to configure my `nginx` to pass the `307` response back to the App, instead of getting stuck in the upstream declaration?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

It seems like when using `nginx` upstream for loadbalancing, i get the following response by steam after logging in:

```
https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?....&openid.realm=https://rest_api&openid.return_to=https://rest_api/login?redirectUrl=exp://THE_ACTUAL_REDIRECT_URL&....
```

this is NOT WORKING

but this is WORKING when I use the plain IP without `nginx`:

```
https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?....&openid.realm=https://111.222.333.444:8081&openid.return_to=https://111.222.333.444:8081/login?redirectUrl=exp://THE_ACTUAL_REDIRECT_URL
```

So it seems to me like the Server running the `loadbalancer/proxy`, is being exposed as `rest_api` to the world.

Comment: when do you get the window? before or after login / redirect?

Comment: after successful login. So the redirect-sending is being executed correctly by the backend. But it doesn't get passed back correctly to the client through `nginx`.

Comment: can you debug the flow in your browser using developer tools? otherwise this will turn into "how to debug my iOS app" where I unfortunately cannot help.

Comment: I did that now and edited the question. I really hope, this helps

Comment: Sounds like you might need to pass `Forwarded` header from proxy to backend. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Forwarded https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/

Comment: Could you alternatively try proxy_pass with IP and not upstream?

Comment: Disregard my "Forwarded" comment, it was a wrong direction.

Comment: I tried reading about the forwarded, but I didn't get it to work properly. Using proxy_pass with a single IP works. But I need the loadbalancer in between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems by default nginx passes `$proxy_host` in the `Host` header (see below), you will need to change that to the actual host:

```
         location / {
                 proxy_pass https://rest_api;
                 proxy_set_header Host $host;
                 // ...
         }
```

> Syntax:   `proxy_set_header field value;`
>
> [...]
>
> By default, only two fields are redefined:
>
> ```
> proxy_set_header Host       $proxy_host;
> proxy_set_header Connection close;
> ```
>
> -- https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header

> `$proxy_host`
>
> name and port of a proxied server as specified in the proxy_pass directive;
>
> -- https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#variables

Comment: Thanks @criztovyl for your patience and help. Your answer fixed my problem:)